# Poor IO performance under heavy load

Tags: io, filesystems, linux-kernel

It seems that I have a problem with Linux IO performance. Working with a project I need to `clear` whole the file from the kernel space. I use the following code pattern:

```
for_each_mapping_page(mapping, index) {
    page = read_mapping_page(mapping, index);
    lock_page(page);
    { kmap // memset // kunmap }
    set_page_dirty(page);
    write_one_page(page, 1);
    page_cache_release(page);
    cond_resched();
}
```

All works fine but with large files (~3Gb+ for me) I see that my system stalls in a strange manner: while this operation is not completed I can't run anything. In other words, all the processes that exists before this operation runs fine, but if I try to run something while this operation I see nothing until it completed.

Is it a kernel's IO scheduling issue or may be I missed something? And how can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

UPD:

According to Kristof's suggestion I've reworked my code and now it looks like this:

```
headIndex = soff >> PAGE_CACHE_SHIFT;
tailIndex = eoff >> PAGE_CACHE_SHIFT;

/**
 * doing the exact @headIndex .. @tailIndex range
 */

for (index = headIndex; index < tailIndex; index += nr_pages) {
    nr_pages = min_t(int, ARRAY_SIZE(pages), tailIndex - index);

    for (i = 0; i < nr_pages; i++) {
        pages[i] = read_mapping_page(mapping, index + i, NULL);
        if (IS_ERR(pages[i])) {
            while (i--)
                page_cache_release(pages[i]);
            goto return_result;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nr_pages; i++)
        zero_page_atomic(pages[i]);

    result = filemap_write_and_wait_range(mapping, index << PAGE_CACHE_SHIFT,
                          ((index + nr_pages) << PAGE_CACHE_SHIFT) - 1);

    for (i = 0; i < nr_pages; i++)
        page_cache_release(pages[i]);

    if (result)
        goto return_result;

    if (fatal_signal_pending(current))
        goto return_result;

    cond_resched();
}
```

As the result I've got better IO performance, but still have problems with huge IO activity while doing concurrent disk access within the same user as caused the operation.

Anyway, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have file I/O in your kernel module? It is considered [non-standard](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0005.3/0061.html) and [bad](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110). I can't answer your question, but I can tell you to try to move this to a userland process.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Well, I have some reasons to get this in the kernel. Besides, I see nothing that shows me why kernel-mode IO is bad.

Comment: This operation will clearly take a while.  Are you running it from a code path that needs to be fast?  Or have you taken some lock before entering this loop that prevents other tasks from successfully running?

Comment: @Peter: Sure, this operation needs some time to be completed, especially on large files. This code runs as a hook via `lsm_inode_unlink`. So, I see nothing that prevents other processes from running except huge IO workload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence you're bypassing the kernels IO scheduler completely.

If you look at the ext2 implementation you'll see it never (well ok, once) calls `write_one_page()`. For large-scale data transfers it uses `mpage_writepages()` instead.

This uses the Block I/O interface, rather than immediately accessing the hardware. This means it passes through the IO scheduler. Large operations will not block the entire systems, as the scheduler will automatically ensure that other operations are interleaved with the large writes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I suppose that something gets wrong with IO scheduling. I'll take a while to rework the code.